# absolutely continuous functions in fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that I have a function $q\in H^{1/2}(0,T)$, is it possible to prove that  $f(t)=\int_0^t q(s)ds$ is absolutely continuous or there is a counterexample for that?
thank you!

Comment: In my opinion, $q \in L^1(0,T)$ is sufficient for the absolute continuity of $f$. Isn't it?

Comment: $q\in L^2(0,T)$ and with a weak derivative in $L^2$. Why you say $L^1$?

Comment: If you have $q \in L^1(0,T)$, the function $f(t) = \int_0^t q(s) ds$ will be absolutely continuous. If I am not mistaken, this just follows from the absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral.